# How to reference constructor of a sealed in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I have the following code

```
class A(val i: Int)
sealed class S {
    class A(val i: Int)
}

fun <T> f(g: (Int) -> T) = Unit

fun test() {
    f(::A)   // OK
    f(::S.A) // error: Unresolved reference A
}
```

so how do I reference constructor of a sealed class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a way to do that: `f(S::A)`